# Cycles materials in BGE

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, game-engine

How would I set the game engine to use cycles materials rather than standard materials. I don't even know where to start!

Comment: As far as I know, though I may be mistaken, you cannot use Cycles materials in the BGE. BGE is older than Cycles, and was never meant to accomodate Cycles, plus, BGE is going to be depreciated (ie not maintained nor added anymore) from 2.8 forward.

Comment: but you can still use Blender Render in the UPBGE Fork and Ketsji that have BGE, no matter where that quasi-mode called 2.8 goes

Comment: You can bake cycles materials into textures and use them. that way.

Answer (score 1):

and the answer is No, you can not use cycles in bge, what you can do is create textures rendered in cycles and use them in bge with their respective uv map.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now with UPBGE 3.x you can run cycles in real time.